# reload section header when tapped on other section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sectionheader

I have a UITableView with two sections in it. I have used custom views for the section headers and also added UITapGestureRecognisers on both of them.

I want to change the data on a section header when I tap on the other section header. How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it would be to add your customs section header views as instance variables on your view controller. That way you can easily reference them whenever a change happens.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is the fact that when you create a tap gesture recognizer, you assign a selector as so:

```
var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: <#AnyObject#>, action: <#Selector#>)
```

Why not just have both taps reference the same selector and update both section headers in the selector method if that is what you are looking for. Perhaps, I am not understanding your question fully though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when the first section header is tapped you perform a selector to set the data you want to display in the second section header. The last thing your selector should do is call

```
self.tableView!.reloadData()
```

to redisplay the table. Only the displayed cells are redrawn so the call performs well.